# how to call java method via solidity contract

Tags: solidity, java

I have my solidity contract

//solidity contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

   contract SimpleStorage { 

    uint public storedData;

      function SimpleStorage(uint initialValue) {
        storedData = initialValue;
       }

       function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
         }

       function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
        return storedData;
       }

    }
```

---

And I have JAVA program like this ,

```
   public class mySpecialClass{

      public int mySpecialfun(int a ,int b){ 
          int c;
            // c =my special treatment of a and b
               return c ;
                           } 
                    }
```

---

I want to call  mySpecialfun() in my contract

eg:

```
      set(mySpecialfun(5,6) /* 5 and 6 just example   */)
```

my problem is to call java program in my contract 
thank you for your help

Comment: you can't do that but you can do the reverse

Answer (score 1):

The smart contract can't access anything outside the blockchain directly. Everything the smart contract does has to be contained within the blockchain. You can access outside resources only indirectly through something called oracles.

So, your contract can not access your Java program.

Comment: first thank you for your answer .Can you explain more the destination of what oracles it is a technology or what. thank you

Comment: https://kndrck.co/posts/ethereum_oracles_a_simple_guide/

Answer (score 0):

Smart contract cannot access anything out of the contract ,but you can access smart contract functions through java's web3j library